# How to make a simple text field validation and button to go to next page with jQuery Mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

This is what I got, but I cannot get the correct way to go load another page if the correct text is added in the textbox. Can someone help me getting the right syntax?

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(document).delegate('[data-role="page"]', 'pageinit', function () {

    var $submit = $(this).find('input[type="submit"]'),
    $text   = $(this).find('input[type="text"]');
    $text.bind('keyup', function () {
        if (this.value == 'llab') {
            $submit.button('enable');
        } else {
            $submit.button('disable');
        }
    }).trigger('keyup');
});
//]]> 

</script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Home -->
        <div data-role="page" id="page1">
            <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
                <h3>
                    Uppgift 1
                </h3>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content">
                <p>
                    Uppgift nummer ett blir att ... 
                </p>
                <img src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Centralstationen, Göteborg&amp;zoom=14&amp;size=288x200&amp;markers=Centralstationen, Göteborg&amp;sensor=false" width="288" height="200" />
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                        <label for="pwtext">
                        </label>
                        <input name="passwordtext" id="pwtext" placeholder="" value="" type="text" />
                    </fieldset>
                </div>
                <input type="submit" data-theme="b" data-icon="check" data-iconpos="left" value="Ta dig vidare" id="sendbtn" name="sendbtn"/>
                <a data-role="button" data-theme="a" href="start.html" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="left">
                    Tillbaka till startsidan
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i hope the below solves your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated answer:**

Here is a complete solution for your question/problem.

**Markup:**

Consists of two pages, login page (page1) and (page2) upon successful login.

```
<!-- Start of first page -->
<div data-role="page" id="page1">

<div data-role="header">
<h1>page1 header</h1>
</div><!-- /header -->

<div data-role="content">   
<p>enter password</p>
<form id="login" action="" method="">
<input name="pwtext" id="pwtext" placeholder="" value="" type="text" class="required" />
<input type="submit" data-theme="b" data-icon="check" data-iconpos="left" value="Ta dig vidare" id="sendbtn" name="sendbtn" />
    </form>

</div><!-- /content -->

<div data-role="footer">
<h4>Page1 Footer</h4>
</div><!-- /footer -->
</div><!-- /page -->

<!-- Start of second page -->
<div data-role="page" id="page2">

<div data-role="header">
<h1>Bar</h1>
</div><!-- /header -->

<div data-role="content">   
<p>password accepted</p>        
<p><a href="#page1">Back to page1</a></p>

</div><!-- /content -->

<div data-role="footer">
<h4>Page2 Footer</h4>
</div><!-- /footer -->
</div><!-- /page -->
```

**Password validation and redirect to next page if the password is correct.**

```
$("#login").submit(function() {

var emptyFields = $(":input.required").filter(function() {

    return !$.trim(this.value).length;
});

if(emptyFields.length) {

            $("#pwtext").css("background-color", "#ffff76");
            $("#pwtext").attr("placeholder", "Passeword required!");
    return false;
}
if ($('#pwtext').val() != 'omar') {
    $("#pwtext").css("background-color", "#ffff76");
    $("#pwtext").attr("placeholder", "Passeword required!");
    return false;
}
if ($('#pwtext').val() == 'omar') {
    $.mobile.changePage("#page2", "slideup");
    return false;
 }
});
```

JSFiddle: [test](http://jsfiddle.net/T9gtn/2/)

Comment: I'm glad I've been of help!

Comment: if I add this code to the document.ready()-function in the page it will work, but it will not if I link from another page. Document.ready are not called. ping @Omar

Comment: `$(document).ready()` is depreciated. use `$(document).on('pageshow')` or `('pagebeforeshow')` or `('pageinit')`. let me know the result :) @jimand

Comment: does not work. Have tried them all. Does it has anything to do with that it is a multi-page and I load this data-role=page @Omar.(document).on('pageshow','[data-role=page]', function(){

Comment: can you send me the code by email? i'll go through it. @jimand